# Criar uma função que retorna informações sobre um file

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho que criar uma simples função que escreve no idle informações sobre um file. Eu  já tinha feito muitas funções deste tipo, já tinha até criado um bloco de notas em C#, mas gostaria de saber se o que estou a fazer está correto e porquê.

As informações que temos que mostrar são: *# de linhas*, *# de palavras* e *# de characters*.

Estou a perguntar isto porque gostaria de ter a certeza, visto que um dos professores reclamou de algumas coisas que não tinha feito, por exemplo o facto que não tinha controlado se uma linha estava vazia ou não.

```
f_name = "text.txt"

import os

def get_file_stats(file_name=""):
    while not os.path.isfile(file_name):
        file_name = input("Enter a valid existing file name: ")

    with open(file_name) as file:
        lines, words, chars = 0, 0, 0

        for line in file: 
            if line:
                lines += 1
                words += len(line.strip().split())

                for c in line: # count the number of chars.
                    if c.isalpha(): # checks if the character is a word character
                        chars += 1

        print("Lines:", lines)
        print("Words:",words)
        print("Chars:",chars)

get_file_stats(f_name)
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível, em general, melhorar esta simples função.

Comment: Sim, é possível.

Answer (score 0):

Está um pouco grande demais este código. Eu faria algo assim:

```py
fname = "text.txt"

num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
num_chars = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()

        if len(words) > 0: 
            num_lines += 1
            num_words += len(words)
            for c in line:
                if c.isalpha():
                    num_chars += 1

print("Lines: ", num_lines)
print("Words: ", num_words)
print("Chars: ", num_chars)
```